# Vim 7.4+ Mapping

Tags: vim

I have recently upgraded my Vim from 7.3 to 7.4.712.  In the process, I've goofed up a couple of my bindings.  Specifically, I want to map ':w' to w and that works, but every time I hit w it saves but it also advances my cursor one word.  Is there a good way I can interrupt the advance behavior without rebinding the 'w' key everywhere?

My vimrc can be found here https://github.com/ZacheryPD/.dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: Don't put comments after mappings. They aren't comments. They are interpreted literally.

Comment: That is incredibly interesting, thanks!  unfortunately, that didn't fix the issue at hand, 


space+w still saved, then advanced one word =/

Comment: You also don't want trailing spaces as those get interpreted literally too.

Comment: THAT WAS IT!  @FDinoff!  Thank you so much, I would NEVER have realized that was the problem.